# Why Sympy does not evaluate this definite integral?

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math, integral

I have tried the following code to evaluate this integral but the output is the integral in LaTeX format and not evaluated.

```
import sympy as smp
g, t,v = smp.symbols('g t v')
expr = smp.sqrt(1 - 1/(g*t +1)**2)
smp.Integral(expr,t)
```

If SymPy can not evaluate this integral, is there any other Python library that can evaluate it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `integrate` rather than `Integral` if you actually want to compute the integral although in this particular case `integrate` fails:

```
In [3]: integrate(expr, t)
Out[3]: 
⌠                         
⎮      ________________   
⎮     ╱         1         
⎮    ╱  1 - ──────────  dt
⎮   ╱                2    
⎮ ╲╱        (g⋅t + 1)     
⌡
```

We can give `integrate` a helping hand by making a change of variables:

```
In [4]: Integral(expr, t)
Out[4]: 
⌠                         
⎮      ________________   
⎮     ╱         1         
⎮    ╱  1 - ──────────  dt
⎮   ╱                2    
⎮ ╲╱        (g⋅t + 1)     
⌡                         

In [5]: Integral(expr, t).transform(g*t + 1, z)
Out[5]: 
⌠                 
⎮      ________   
⎮     ╱     1     
⎮    ╱  1 - ──    
⎮   ╱        2    
⎮ ╲╱        z     
⎮ ───────────── dz
⎮       g         
⌡                 

In [6]: Integral(expr, t).transform(g*t + 1, z).doit()
Out[6]: 
⎧       ⅈ⋅z                ⎛1⎞          ⅈ               1      
⎪- ────────────── - ⅈ⋅acosh⎜─⎟ + ────────────────  for ──── > 1
⎪       _________          ⎝z⎠          _________      │ 2│    
⎪      ╱      1                        ╱      1        │z │    
⎪     ╱  -1 + ──                 z⋅   ╱  -1 + ──               
⎪    ╱         2                     ╱         2               
⎪  ╲╱         z                    ╲╱         z                
⎨                                                              
⎪         z             ⎛1⎞          1                         
⎪   ───────────── + asin⎜─⎟ - ───────────────       otherwise  
⎪        ________       ⎝z⎠          ________                  
⎪       ╱     1                     ╱     1                    
⎪      ╱  1 - ──              z⋅   ╱  1 - ──                   
⎪     ╱        2                  ╱        2                   
⎩   ╲╱        z                 ╲╱        z                    
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                               g 

In [9]: Integral(expr, t).transform(g*t + 1, z).doit().subs(z, g*t + 1)
Out[9]: 
⎧         ⎛   1   ⎞        ⅈ⋅(g⋅t + 1)                        ⅈ                           1          
⎪- ⅈ⋅acosh⎜───────⎟ - ────────────────────── + ────────────────────────────────  for ──────────── > 1
⎪         ⎝g⋅t + 1⎠        _________________        _________________                │         2│    
⎪                         ╱          1             ╱          1                      │(g⋅t + 1) │    
⎪                        ╱  -1 + ──────────       ╱  -1 + ────────── ⋅(g⋅t + 1)                      
⎪                       ╱                 2      ╱                 2                                 
⎪                     ╲╱         (g⋅t + 1)     ╲╱         (g⋅t + 1)                                  
⎨                                                                                                    
⎪       ⎛   1   ⎞          g⋅t + 1                         1                                         
⎪   asin⎜───────⎟ + ───────────────────── - ───────────────────────────────           otherwise      
⎪       ⎝g⋅t + 1⎠        ________________        ________________                                    
⎪                       ╱         1             ╱         1                                          
⎪                      ╱  1 - ──────────       ╱  1 - ────────── ⋅(g⋅t + 1)                          
⎪                     ╱                2      ╱                2                                     
⎩                   ╲╱        (g⋅t + 1)     ╲╱        (g⋅t + 1)                                      
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                                                  g
```